# Can not use of require() to include any module

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use

```
require('http');
```

to include any module. But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Note: http is just an example. It occcurs for any module.

Comment: You're going to have to give us some context for this.

Comment: is your installation of node.js correct? if yes, which version of node.js are you using?

Comment: What does the rest of your file look like? How do you execute it?

Comment: `require()` is built into node.js so if `require()` is actually not defined, then you must not be running your code in node.js or your installation is somehow messed up.  Please describe exactly how you run your code and perhaps show us the whole file that you are running.

Comment: As of now, I am trying to just include nodejs modules using require(). I can't tell what exactly I am going to code. Additionally, I think installation of node was successful, as it didn't give me any error after installation.